# How many ways are there to describe a regular 2D arc?

Tags: c#, java, c++, api, geometry

In the pursuit of developing a graphical software package, I have to deal with 2D regular arcs in the library. As such I would like to know what are the various ways of describing an arc, currently I have the following:

1. Three points, two on the circumference, one at the center
2. Three points, all on the circumference

Are there any other ways? As I would like to provide a series of API's that correctly represent all the various way one can draw a regular 2D arc on canvas.

Comment: This is really more of a geometry question than a programming question. Perhaps try [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way.  Can you tell us how this relates?

Comment: It's NOT a mathematical problem. Well, as phrased it is, but the mathematical answer is infinite.

Comment: I've voted to reopen because the question has been rewritten to show how it relates.

Answer (score 3):

Here are values we could have been given:

- `l` - some reference line, for instance vertical or horizontal line
- `O` - center point
- `R` - radius length
- `a1`, `a2` - angles of ending points, given as between some reference line (`l`) and a line that go both through given point and center point
- `a` - total arc angle, given as between two lines that each go through one of end points, and both go through center point
- `t1`, `t2` - angles of tangents, which are actually orthogonal to `a1` and `a2`, and so require `l` as well, and can be used wherever `a1` and `a2` are used
- `t` - angle between tangents, which is supplementary to `a`, `t = PI - a`
- `M` - middle arc point
- `P` - arbitrary arc point
- `P1`, `P2` - end arc points
- `c` - [chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28geometry%29) angle, given as between chord and reference line (`l`), and could be obtained as `c = PI - (a1 + a2) / 2` (I think so... It's late)
- `C` - chord length
- `H` - chord height, given as maximal distance between arc and chord
- `L` - arc length, which is basically `L = a * R`

Values `a1, a2, t1, t2, c` require implicit information about `l`.

The list above is not complete, so is not the list below, but you get the point. The arc can be described with:

- `O, P1, P2` - your first
- `P1, P2, P` - your second
- `O, r, a1, a2, l` - slomojo's one
- `O, P1, a`
- `O, M, a`
- `O, c, C, l`
- `O, P1, c`
- `P1, C, H, c, l`
- and many more...

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a number of others involving the radius and the start and end angles.

Essentially you can pick any combination that results in sufficient data from 3 points, the radius, start and end angles, or arc angle.

Answer (score 1):

Many drawing API's use a method like this...

- Centre point (x, y), radius, start-angle, end-angle